# Issues While getting response from api using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am integrating detail api in my app but i can't under stand that how to get data from array i am putting my response here for better understanding

```
 {
"success": "1",
"data": {
    "service_list": [
        {
      "service_id": "11",
      "fk_user_id": "77",
      "fk_bus_id": "0",
      "fk_sub_cate_id": "1",
      "service_name": "Business Cards",
       "service_desc": "Business Cards",
       "service_price": "500",
       "service_img1": "https://www.kwikmypay.com/mode_share/modeshare_admin/assets/images/business/ser_pquat1531379189.png",
       "service_img2": "https://www.kwikmypay.com/mode_share/modeshare_admin/assets/images/business/ser_hjzty1531379189.png",
       "service_img3": "https://www.kwikmypay.com/mode_share/modeshare_admin/assets/images/business/ser_rmgxb1531379189.png",
       "service_img4": "https://www.kwikmypay.com/mode_share/modeshare_admin/assets/images/business/ser_kptyq1531379189.png",
       "service_img5": "https://www.kwikmypay.com/mode_share/modeshare_admin/assets/images/business/ser_xwmlq1531379189.png"
        }
    ]
},
"message": ""
}
```

Here Is my response i want the **service list** array to print in table view can any one please help me

**Here Is my Answer**

```
   let busdetail = ["user_id":u_id,"access_token":acc_tkn,"bus_id":busid] as [String:Any]
        print(busdetail)
        Alamofire.request(businessDetail, method: .post, parameters: busdetail).responseJSON
            {
                response in

                print(response)
                let result = response.result

                if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                    if let serlist = dict["data"]{
                        if let s_list = serlist["service_list"]{

                        self.servicelist = s_list as! [AnyObject]
                        self.tbl_expand.reloadData()
                        //self.tbl_servicelist.reloadData()
                        //self.dropDown.items = categorylist as! [AnyObject] as! [String]
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.hideLoader()
                //self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
```

Comment: what problem you are facing show your code

Comment: i am new to ios so i can't under stand how to get response from data: {serviewlist[]}

Comment: your servicelist is an array of dictionary

Comment: its an dictionary

Comment: i just want to that how to get response from service list array in this

Comment: yes i understand your problem

Comment: yes then please help me to solve this

Comment: show your api data please

Comment: u mean Api response?

Comment: yes got it.....

Comment: please check question already i post the response in question

Comment: do this if facing problem let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func demoApi() {
Alamofire.request("yourapi", method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

    switch(response.result) {
    case .success(_):
        if let json= response.result.value as? [String:Any] {   
        if let response = json["data"] as? [String:Any],
        let ServiceList= response["service_list"] as? [[String:Any]] {

     for servicelist in ServiceList {
        let service_id= servicelist ["service_id"] as! String
        let service_name= servicelist ["service_name"] as! String
        let service_img1= servicelist ["service_img1"] as! String

    }
  }
}

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.yourTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        break

    case .failure(_):
        print("Error")
        break

    }
}

 }
```

Comment: Yes exactly i am looking for this Thank You

Comment: you got what you want

Comment: Yes i got it and i get it what i am looking for

Comment: happy coding :)

Comment: Yes Thank you For Helping